# CurlFTPFS Not allowing users to change files

Tags: fuse

I have installed `curlftpfs` as per instructions I found on the net. I am mounting it in my `fstab` file using this command:

```
curlftpfs#ftp://user:pass@IP /media/FTP fuse rw,uid=1000,umask=0777,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8  0   0
```

Problem is that my user cannot edit anything in this folder. I can view anything I want, but I cannot edit anything. Anytime I try to edit something I get access denied errors.

What would I need to change to allow any user on my system to edit files mounted here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out changing permissions and `umask`. `umask` should be `002` according to this nice tutorial here:

http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/understanding-linux-unix-umask-value-usage.html

Then I have to also specify what group ID I desire when mounting. I also found out that during boot this sometimes doesn't work because of the network, so I had to add `_netdev` to allow it to mount after the network.

All works now. So the final line for the `fstab` file is:

```
curlftpfs#ftp://user:pass@IP /media/FTP fuse rw,uid=1000,gid=1000,umask=002,user,suid,allow_other,exec,auto,utf8,_netdev  0   0
```

Of course replacing `uid` and `gid` with your user ID and group ID for your user. After this little change though it works perfectly using `sudo mount -a` or at boot.

`umask` was the big thing, unless both user and group had write permissions it wasn't working for me. So `0022` doesn't work for `umask` since that makes user writeable but not group. For some reason without group it just wouldn't work.

Comment: Doesn't work for me, not even with umaks=000, still read-only even though apparently I have write access to files.